# mongod main process killed by KILL signal

Tags: mongodb

One of the mongo nodes in the replica set went down today. I couldn't find what happened but when i checked the logs on the server, I saw this message 'mongod main process killed by KILL signal'. I tried googling for more information but failed. Basically i like to know what is KILL signal, who triggered it and possible causes/fixes.

Mongo version 3.2.10 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [KILL signal](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html) means that the app will be killed instantly and there is no chance left for the process to exit cleanly. It is issued by the system when something goes very wrong.

If this is the only log left, it was killed abruptly. Probably this means that your system ran out of memory (I've had this problem with other processes before). You could check if swap is configured on your machine (by using `swapon -s`), but perhaps you should consider adding more memory to your server, because swap would be just for it not to break, as it is very slow.

Another thing worth looking at is the free disk space left and the syslog (`/var/log/syslog`)